# Replace every onclick of the page with img src link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I use a webpage where I want to replace the `onclick`s, of a bunch of links, with the modified `src` link of the `<img>` each link contains.

For example, the Greasemonkey script should change this:

```
<p class="listphotos">
    <a onclick="alert('I'm a really annoying function! X'); return false;" href="#">
        <img alt="photo" src="http://.../min/x.jpg">
    </a>
    <a onclick="alert('I'm a really annoying function! Y'); return false;" href="#">
        <img alt="photo" src="http://.../min/y.jpg">
    </a>
</p>
```

To this:

```
<p class="listphotos">
    <a onclick="http://.../max/x.jpg" href="http://.../max/x.jpg">
        <img alt="photo" src="http://.../min/x.jpg">
    </a>
    <a onclick="http://.../max/y.jpg" href="http://.../max/y.jpg">
        <img alt="photo" src="http://.../min/y.jpg">
    </a>
</p>
```

I've tried this (see also [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAH6L/1/)):

```
var link = $("p.listphotos a img").prop("src").replace("min", "max");

$("p.listphotos a").prop("onclick", link);
$("p.listphotos a").prop("href", link);
```

but the right pictures do not get linked.

Comment: I Think working with classes would be your best solution, give them a button class or something and in your jQuery you work all from that certain class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `onclick` to a link is an error. `onclick` needs to be valid javascript. But, since it looks like you're trying to "delink" those photos, best to remove the `onclick`s altogether.

Also, you can't set the `href` that way (unless you want every link to go to the same photo).  You need to loop.  jQuery's `.each()` should do the trick. Like so:

```
$("p.listphotos a img").each ( function () {
    //-- `this` is each target image, one at a time
    var jThis   = $(this);
    //-- More robust replace
    var bigLink = jThis.prop ("src").replace (/\bmin\b/i, "max");

    //-- The img parent is the link we're after.
    jThis.parent ().prop ("href", bigLink).removeProp ("onclick");
} );
```

---

Note that [`prop` and `removeProp` are the correct way to kill an `onclick`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/#entry-longdesc). But, if you inspect the page source in some browsers, the attribute will still be there.  Don't worry, the `onclick` will no longer function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this

```
var numberClick=0;
var Images= ['image1.png','image2.png'];

function changeIndex(index){
   if (index >=0 && index < Images.length){   
      $("p.listphotos a img").attr("src", Images[index]);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

then you can use it in this way

```
function showImage(){
     if (changeIndex(numberClick)){
        numberClick+=1;
     }
     else{
        numberClick=0;
     }
}
```

and then

```
$("p.listphotos a img").click(function(){
   showImage();
   return false;
 });
```